# iphone doesn't play the notification sound

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I add sound to my notification, but it is not played.

I tried these:

```
notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

notif.soundName = @"sound.caf";
```

help??

Comment: Is your test phone in silent mode?

Comment: How have you created the sound? How long is it? What is the output from `afinfo sound.caf`?

Answer (score 0):

So does your full code (sound only) look like this?

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notif.firedate = //Whenever
notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

If your code checks out, then it must be an issue with the iPhone.  Does it work in the simulator?